# $A-C \sim B-D$ if $A\sim B$, $C\sim D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that if $A\sim B$, $C\sim D$ and $C\subset A$ and $D\subset B$, then $A-C \sim B-D$.

Here $A\sim B$ if and only if there exist a bijection $f:A\to B$.

Comment: Are you so sure this is even true? If I were you, I would spend a bit more time examining the case where $A,B,C,D$ all have the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is not true.

Comment: Yup! Pretty, neat huh? You might consider answering your own question to get feedback on your counter-example.

Comment: Consider $A=B=\mathbb{N}$; $C=\{2, 3, \ldots\}$ and $D=\{3, 4, \ldots\}$. Thus $C\sim D$ but $\{1\}$ is not equipotent to $\{1, 2\}$.

Comment: Perfect. For a more extreme example, you could use $A=B=C=\mathbb{N}$, $D=\{2,4,6,8,\ldots\}$. Now $A,B,C,D$ are all equipotent, but $\varnothing$ is not equipotent to $\{1,3,5,7,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Can we make this statement true by imposing some further restrictions on the sets?

Comment: @Eric: It holds if you assume $A,B$ (hence also $C,D$) are finite. It also holds if you assume if $A,B$ are infinite and that $C,D$ have strictly smaller cardinality (and in fact one has $A \sim B \sim (A - C) \sim (B-D)$ in this case regardless of whether or not $C \sim D$ is true).